# Alternative to hardcoding Python interpreter exec during unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, command-line

Assume a `unittest` test, in which a multi-line output file is generated via a Python script (that uses argparse) and the equality of that file against an expected outcome is compared.

```
def test_actual_vs_expected_output(self):
    actual_inp = '/path_to/actu_inp.txt'
    expect_otp = '/path_to/expe_otp.txt'
    actual_otp = '/path_to/actu_otp.txt'
    myScript = '/path_to/myScript.py'
    cmd_list = ['python2', myScript,
                '-i', actual_inp,
                '-o', actual_otp]
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(' '.join(cmd_list), shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print e.output
    if os.path.isfile(actual_otp):
        expect_str = open(expect_otp).read()
        actual_str = open(actual_otp).read()
    self.assertMultiLineEqual(expect_str, actual_str)
```

How can I avoid hardcoding the calling of `python2` (i.e., in `cmd_list` of the above example)? After all, the Python2 interpreter may be called differently on different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call Python in a subprocess, you can use the currently running Python interpreter. The full path of this interpreter is given by the global variable [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

So, you can write:

```
import sys

cmd_list = [sys.executable, myScript,
            '-i', actual_inp,
            '-o', actual_otp]
```

A comment: the [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function accept a list of arguments, so you can pass the *cmd_list* parameter as-is (you don't need to join):

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd_list, shell=True)
```

Another comment: A python script may write error messages in STDERR. You may consider an alternative to `check_output` to get the error message or use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.